# Is it possible to inject dependency inside java interface using guice - java

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to inject dependency inside my interface

```
public interface TestInject {

   @Inject
   Mydependency dependencyToCall;

    default void processInput(String inputToCheck) {
        //some lines of code
        dependencyToCall.process(inputToCheck)
    } // If i dont do this then all implementation has to implement same code. 

  void handleError()//will be overwritten by implementation class

}
```

the above code throws error `variable dependencyToCall might not be initialized`

Is it possible to inject inside interface ?

Or do i have to introduce abstract class to solve redundant code issue

Comment: `dependencyToCall` is implicitly both `static` and `final`, as are all fields declared in an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will not work. Check the official document about Java Interface, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-9.html):

*An interface declaration introduces a new reference type whose members are classes, interfaces, constants, and methods. **This type has no instance variables**, and typically declares one or more abstract methods; otherwise unrelated classes can implement the interface by providing implementations for its abstract methods. Interfaces may not be directly instantiated.*

Guess you should change to use abstract class